# my same count query is showing on dev log to be run 25 times. is it fine or something wrong with code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

[image]

This user 73729 has 25 notes. but does it mean that this query should run 25 times? is it actually running 25 times or its just log that shows it running 25 times where actually its running just 1 time?

Comment: Your query is actually running 25 times. Confirm that you have written that query outside the loop statement.

Comment: Your query is definetely running 25 times and that's a problem. You could post your code in the question so we could probably come up with a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is definitely running 25 times.